# React Native Expo Notifications token value is undefined or empty

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo, token

I can't get the token value for notifications in my application with expo. I can get the token value in the Expo application, but I cannot access the token value for notifications in the real device. My code is exactly the same as in the expo example. What am I missing or doing wrong?

My code example: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#api
My other code example: https://resimlink.com/NBUa1r4

Comment: I solved the problem. I'm explaining for those who encounter the same error. For Android, the application needs to be registered to firebase. Then firebase gives you a json file. You need to put it in the main directory of the project as well. Helpful article and video...

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu-ayWwRCOA
Article Url: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/